# How to clean the index values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
Abomasnow                   Grass   Ice     494     90  92  75  92  85  60  
AbomasnowMega Abomasnow     Grass   Ice     594     90  132     105 132 105
Abra                    Psychic     Psychic     310     25  20  15  105 55 
Absol                      Dark     Dark    465     65  130     60  75  60  75 
AbsolMega Absol
```

I have a dataframe like this which has some dirty index values. For eg: I need to change the value from `AbomasnowMega Abomasnow` to `Mega Abomasnow` and similarly to other such occurrences, i.e I need to perform this wherever there is the word `Mega`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option where you can use `.str.replace()` method with regex, with `.*(?=Mega)`, it will remove all characters before the last *Mega* in your string, in case you are not familiar with `regex`, `.*` matches all characters greedily, `?=` is look ahead syntax, which constraints the matching pattern directly in front of `Mega`:

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace(".*(?=Mega)", "")

df.index
# Index(['Abomasnow', 'Mega Abomasnow', 'Abra', 'Absol', 'Mega Absol'], dtype='object', name=0)
```